# julia - HTTP.WebSockets timeouts not working

Tags: julia

Neither of the timeouts for HTTP.WebSockets.open() work.  I expect the connect timeout to timeout when the internet is down and it cant connect, and idle timeout to timeout when its actively connected and the internet goes down.

```
using HTTP.WebSockets
WebSockets.open(url;
            connect_timeout=10, # stop trying after n seconds 
            idle_timeout=10, # disconnect after no messages for n seconds
            retry=false)
```

I'm on HTTP.jl v1.8.1

Comment: You are using `readtimeout=10` instead of `connect_timeout=10`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. In fact when I add it it hangs on open.